# Node-RED use of more than one environment variable in an input field

Tags: node-red

I have a simple problem and I can't figure it out.

I have a subflow in which I have defined 3 environment variables.
There I also have a `http in` node.
What I want to do is to set the url field of the node like this:
`${some_var}/${other_var}`
When I use a single environment variable in the URL field it works fine but when I do it like in the example it doesnt work.
I have tried many things but cant get it to work.
I also searched the internet for about 2 hours now and cant find anything.

Could it be that something like that isn't supported by Node-RED?
Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation on using environment variables within Node-RED is here: https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables (the top search result on google).

The second sentence says:

> This only works if it replaces the entire property - it cannot be used to substitute just part of the value. For example, it is not possible to use `CLIENT-${HOST}`.

As you are inside a subflow, you can define a property of the subflow using the environment variable type - this type does support joining env vars together. You can then use that subflow property as the env var in your node.

The following screenshot shows how to define an env var called `MY_URL`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No you can not do this.

You can not concatenate environment variables in node configuration fields. The runtime will only take the value of a environment variable and replace the whole field with it, not assemble a string from multiple environment variables and static strings.

See the second paragraph in the [docs](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables):

> This only works if it replaces the entire property - it cannot be used
>   to substitute just part of the value. For example, it is not possible
>   to use CLIENT-${HOST}.

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed this part in the docu. Is there a way around? I want a string with the two environment variables in the field. Because I dont see an other way of setting the URL field of the http in node.

Comment: See my answer for how to use subflow env vars to do what you want